# Bonus bounty points based on question value

Tags: feature-request, bounty

If a question gets a lot of upvotes, I think there should be either "free" bounty points ("your question was good, we'll spot your bounty for you"), a bounty multiplier ("we'll double your bounty"), or something else along those lines. The point is that the answer to a good/great question has value to the community, and shouldn't cost the asker as many reputation points. It would also increase the incentive for the community to answer good questions.

Has something like this been considered?

Comment: Sometimes you find altruists, that offer bounties on other people's questions. Anyway I don't see any benefit from your proposal(s). If you find a good answer, just upvote it. No need to apply any extra rep given on these.

Comment: A long while ago, a 50-point bonus was automatically added to every bounty, but this was removed as it was prone to abuse. (This was back when bounties could only be started by the OP, and awarding a bounty was strongly tied with accepting an answer.)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? Its a valid suggestion.  Just because you don't agree with it doesn't mean it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not support this feature request.

First, when the OP puts a bounty on their own question, they get more eyeballs. If their question is that great, more eyeballs will translate to upvotes. **So the OP *already* does get a refund of a sort on their bounty.**

Ok, when someone puts a bounty on someone else's question, the bounty giver does not benefit from this. Life is unfair.

Second, **a bounty is a mechanism which is *parallel* to voting.** It is a sign that someone has looked at the question and that they find it worthy of extra attention. So worthy, in fact, that they are willing to give away their own reputation to get the question more attention. What you are proposing would blur or eliminate this distinction. It may not be important to you but **it is very important to me to know that if a question has a 200 bounty on it, this means that a user has found the question so valuable that they are willing to give away 200 points *of their own reputation*.**

Third, **what you are proposing would have perverse effects.** The questions that are about trivial issues that a lot of people learning a new programming language probably run into get upvoted quickly and eventually get upvoted up into the stratosphere. Those questions that originate from trying to do more sophisticated work do not get upvoted as much. The latter are those who really need the bounties to get attention. Your proposal would favor the former type of question which really do *not* need bounties to get attention.