# How to highlight difficult or old questions and then reward the answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is the flip-side of the [fastest gun problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible/267104#267104).  Yeah, some folks are going to specialize in super-fast answers to easy questions and get more rep points than deserved, but that's not the end of the world in and of itself. (i.e. life's not fair, get used to it!)

The bigger problem is that this has the side effect of causing interesting but more difficult questions to get ignored.  Typical example:  someone asks a question that gets a lot of views and two or more upvotes, but it's hard enough that no one can answer within an hour or so.

Depending on the tags, this question will quickly fall down the list and stop getting any more views or upvotes even though it's clearly a good question.  Additionally, anyone looking at the question now knows that even a good answer is probably maxing out at 25 points coming only from the author of the question.  Again, forget the fairness of it, there is the further problem that even if the question gets answered, it is less likely to turn up in future search results.

I realize this issue is addressed in theory with some of the other lists and badges, but don't think any of these really solves it.  For example, "active" is cluttered with minor edits and "unanswered" is cluttered with things that were answered in comments or possibly can't be anwered.  Plus, the vast majority of people just stick with the default queue (newest).

Possible solutions:

1. A new algorithmic list/tab, ideally made the default list.  The top posts would be:  newer, with upvotes, and unanswered or recently answered.  "Newer" might include non-trivial edits if gaming of that could be avoided.  In particular, a question with upvotes but no answers, ought to be very near the top, and if it is answered, ought to stay there for a little while longer so that the answer can also get some attention.
   In another thread, this [reddit solution](http://www.redditblog.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) for comments was mentioned and it could perhaps be applied to the lists rather than answers to questions.
2. Some kind of reputation reward.  Something sort of like a bounty that is automatic and in proportion to both upvotes and how old the question is.  But like a bounty, it would require that the author of the question selects it or it receives at least two upvotes.  I know badges like Necromancer reward this, but I think that's inadequate.

**Edit to add:**  In response to several comments, I'd like to restate the problem as follows.  When viewing a specific tag, we have lots of tabs that do one thing well (newest, active, etc.) but nothing that *combines* them in an intelligent way.  The result is that we seem to have a stable equilibrium on the default view (newest).

Sketch of a possible answer based on comments:  Start with the bounties tab, but then add two things.  First, have some limited ability for people to set small bounties for free.  Second, have some automated bounties set (e.g. for relatively new, upvoted question with no answers).  I think that these new forms of bounty could have pretty small values.  The point is really to give them a spotlight so they get more views.  Much of the reward would end up coming from more upvotes due to more views.

**Mandatory response to duplicate flag:**  I think this is fairly different.  That question simply proposed an automatic bounty for upvoted questions.  None of the proposals here do that, except in combination with other things (like the question having gone unanswered for some amount of time).  There are also some other things discussed here that are not discussed there.

Comment: What's wrong with the current bounty system?

Comment: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/165773)

Comment: @gnat  Thanks, I was not aware of that question.  Has "bumping" changed since that question was asked?  It seems to me all that matters in the "newest" queue is when the question was originally asked (unless it is deleted and re-posted).

Comment: as far as I know [meta-tag:bump]ing works the same as before, nothing has changed

Comment: Bounties are good as far as they go, but underutilized b/c most people hate to give up 50+ points and it shouldn't be necessary IMO to penalize one person to reward another.  We don't penalize someone for upvoting someone else, for example.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the idea of a small quantity of older upvoted  unanswered questions from my followed tags being plonked onto my default questions view. I think a reputation reward could just encourage crappy answers to these though from people taking a punt.

Comment: Strange to me the system doesn't help me give a well-researched, awesome answer more rep than a merely useful one (short of a +50 bounty, as JohnE notes). I don't expect rep to be a fair or precise thing, but if SE highly values research, etc., even on less-viewed q's, seems the system should make some gesture at helping folks acknowledge the extra effort. Conversely, it's so odd that my highest-voted SO answer took no research and barely any writing, and is something another user would've dashed off in a couple minutes if I hadn't.

Comment: An issue with any 'super-upvote' is ensuring that they don't end up used all the time and become just a formality everyone does after a 'regular' upvote. One idea: +X for stars from users >Y rep (possibly only first Z stars/user/`$TIME_PERIOD`).

Comment: (Or, though I like this one a lot less, mini-bounties, on existing answers only, at a (<50) rep cost, and they don't make the question 'featured'. You might even lose a bit more rep than you give the answerer. Maybe a second click on an answer's arrow gives you a popup to give one. And since someone'll say it, I *do* already comment "wow, this answer is awesome")

Comment: why not *simply* add a *difficulty level* to a question (1 given by requestor for the beginning of the post, than confirmed/adapted by people with higher reputation to keep something coherent in the system). We still have *High score shooter*  people (hard to avoid) but for majority, this will allow to focus on level they could answer (in time and/or competency/knowledge) and with *reward* corresponding a bit more.

Comment: i use `favourite question` feature as it explained here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276408/how-to-track-interesting-questions/276410 and here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252512/whats-the-use-of-favourite-this-question. When a question got answered I get back, read an answer and often upvote it. i would prefer it is to be more explicit (say, special tab in user profile "I want to know the answer"), because count of favourite stars on a question is an estimation of upvotes on a future answer, and top unanswered questions have many upvotes but just few favourite stars

Comment: and irony is that this question too got so many upvotes and still 0 answers ... nice question +1

Comment: How about giving users a "free" 50 points bounty with a significant cooldown? Or would that be too prone to abuse?

Comment: @user1129884 Hmm, maybe monthly or every 500 rep you gain. That's an interesting idea.

Comment: I like the idea of using the number of stars or upvotes to increase visibility of a question or the reward for answering it. You could also include information from the review Triage section. If everyone has said "this is a good question", it has upvotes & favourites, it could have an increased reward or visibility - and i don't think that's prone to abuse.

Comment: @user1129884: I feel like while it will take some tweaking, you're on the right track. Bounties can only be offered on older questions (more than two days old), and your suggestion addresses the very real barrier that many questioners have, in that they either don't even have enough rep to offer a bounty, or that doing so would be too large a sacrifice. That said, it leaves some issues unaddressed: first and foremost, many new users won't know how to use bounties at all, never mind a "free bounty"; secondly, addressing this issue presumes that the SO community (continued in next comment...)

Comment: (continued from previous comment...) has the bandwidth to answer all questions. On that second point, I generally don't have the time to watch SO continuously nor answer every question I could. I already tend to scan through the older, unanswered questions (yes, meaning that good questions with bad answers get neglected), and answer what I have time for. Giving a "free bounty" for new users to use might improve perceived "fairness", but I'm not sure it would actually lead to more answers.

Comment: @ChrisF: _"What's wrong with the current bounty system?"_ Almost everything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - please elucidate.

Comment: For my money - it's quite good for "I want my question answered, here's a reward for the extra effort". It's not nearly so good for the general purpose goal of developing good quality answers to more difficult questions.

Comment: re #2 a pseudo bounty presumably from SE vs a user.  Interesting, but so many Qs in general are from one-time posters that the likelihood that they might be around to accept seems slim.  The most any answers are likely to get is the default half-price mark down amount.  Perhaps none if the Q is unanswered because it is crap, unclear, old tech, dead language or a dozen other reasons making the 2 UpVs a bit less likely.

Comment: Related: [Can we blow away some of the Tumbleweeds?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295713/can-we-blow-away-some-of-the-tumbleweeds)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bonus bounty points based on question value](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278980/bonus-bounty-points-based-on-question-value)

Comment: @Louis That's related, but it's definitely not a duplicate. Firstly, there's more to this question than just the automated bounty part. Secondly, the focus there is high-scoring questions, while here it's old questions.

Comment: @Dukeling This question is a mishmash of multiple proposals that have been made in the past.

Comment: Mutiny on the bounty

Comment: @Louis -- A mishmash or combination of old proposals is not a duplicate if it combines them in a useful way, as I hoped this did (though as a relative newbie I'm sure there are old and relevant questions which I did not turn up in search).  The bounty aspect in particular is not a really large part of the question, but seemed to attract a relatively large share of the comments.  But perhaps you are also aware of other questions that are closer to this question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like this proposal, because ... well, it feels like it should be 'worth more' having a dig through the unanswered questions and giving a decent answer than being fastest to answer an easy but widely seen question.

That's above and beyond the current bounty system, which - with the best will in the world - doesn't seem to get a lot of use, because in no small part it's zero sum.

So what I'd suggest is some sort of 'bounty accumulator' that over time adds a modest bonus rep award to older questions. For the 'tumbleweeds' maybe 10 rep per week, and for any questions with upvotes - maybe they gain the bonus a little faster. Capping this at a certain rep level. Say for the sake of argument: 200 rep cap. That's the daily limit.

If an answer passes the criteria for bounty acceptance (e.g. upvotes or acceptance) this bonus is awarded.

In this way we encourage review of older questions, because more people are looking for opportunities to gain rep (and frankly, they don't at the moment because older questions don't get upvoted).  This in turn means more eyes to edit/improve/close, and more attention generally.

I would add that *generally* the whole point of reputation and gamification is to use a 'reward' in order to drive behaviours. It's clearly not doing that currently - at least, not sufficiently. But as magic unicorn points are basically a free resource, there's no real reason to adjust or skew them based on *what* is being answered/upvoted.

Perhaps as an alternative - scale rep award based on question activity in general - low scoring questions gain lower rep awards than higher scoring questions. That's a bit simpler overall, and will perhaps yield a better result (because a 'good, but unanswered' question might attract more eyes for more rewards - although it does perhaps consign questions with initial downvotes to a downward spiral of decay and neglect)

Comment: While I support this or something similar (see user1129884's proposal of "free bounty"), and agree it might address perceived "fairness" on answering questions, it's unclear to me that it would result in an improvement in the number or quality of answers on SO. As I mention in comments above, targeting the reward side of answering presumes that there is bandwidth on SO users part to answer more questions than they already do now. I'm sure there are other users similar to me who already sift through older questions, low rep-to-effort notwithstanding. We already answer as much as we...

Comment: ...have time for. Until someone creates a system that rewards answers by giving them some portion of their time back, it's not clear to me that more rep reward is really helpful.

Comment: I think this is as simple as drawing more eyes to sifting the older questions, and therefore more deleting/closing/upvoting and improving. And ideally answering. I think there is bandwidth there - occasionally I go for a rummage in the old-question bin, but I don't think many do.

Comment: I find most of the old questions through the related questions on the right and google when I happen upon problems similar to those I face. Maybe they can add a feature to put older questions near the top when they were recently upvoted

Comment: Maybe consider only count upvotes for higher rep users (2K+?) for such "bounty" to limit possible upvote spamming... And I'd probably do nothing for 0 votes questions.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that free bounties will help much. It just means that every user will be able to put a bounty once a month with little relation with the quality of the question - only with the importance of question for OP.

In current system, what would be closer to that is the possibility to offer a bounty on someone else's question. Badges exists for that (Investor and Altruist) but are seldom awarded (resp. 10.3k and 5.2k).

But IMHO the main problem is to be able to identify good unanswered questions. Upvoted questions with no answer for several days, or with no accepted answer are good candidates, but we know that some questions were answered in comments or that some users simply forget to accept one answer.

I am not sure that it is really worth it(*), but I think that the only solution would be to set up a new queue for that : when a question reaches the above threshold (x upvote no answer for y days - or equivalent with no accepted answers), it will enter the queue. Then if 4 members think it is good, it goes in a list where should only exists questions really deserving an answer. At the opposite, if 4 members think it is not so good it definitevely exits the queue.

The difference with the other proposals is that here human beings will use their intelligence to select questions with no answers but deserving one. As we do for questions just deserving to be closed : the system automatically detects candidates, and members vote.

We could propose higher reps for answering such questions, but IMHO their simple presence in a list of manually selected questions should have the equivalent of the well known *meta* effect. And then badges for offering bounties of such questions would be plainly relevant.

(*) I'm pretty sure that it would be efficient, but I also understand that it means setting a new queue, determining thresholds, minimum qualification for voter ...

Comment: Good answer!  I was torn between this and Sobrique's answer and decided to just pick the one with the higher vote total.  Thanks to everyone for the thoughtful comments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an additional reputation bonus is necessary. If the question is going to show up in the lists most people look at for a little while, that should draw almost the same amount of attention (and thus appropriate votes) as a new question.

Also, a reputation bonus for random old questions could be harmful because it's *random* - some of these could be the worst of the worst, thus encouraging answering them could be actively harmful in the long term (by supporting the notion that these questions are acceptable).

Comment: Surely it'll just attract attention and thus edit/close/downvote too though?

Comment: @Sobrique Perhaps, but there'd be additional incentive to answer it instead of taking some other action or answering some other question.

Comment: True. But that's the case now as well. (Perhaps it shouldn't be?)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem.** I think it's that per-tag question lists are pretty useless. I just look at "Newest" for  my favorite tags: for R and some of its packages. The bounties there are either (i) awards for something well done or (ii) mind-numbing requests to graph something *just so*. Neither is very interesting.

---

As @SergeBallesta suggested, I think a new manually curated per-tag list is the answer. In the new question UI, the "popular" tab doesn't even filter by tag, so let's replace that. Alternately, the per-tag bounty tab is rarely crowded.

**An idea for highlighting:** At some cost, each user can highlight a question, based on whatever criteria they like and irrespective of the question's attributes (apart from not already being highlighted or under bounty). When highlighting, the user selects a particular tag, and the question will show up in a question list for that tag for a week.

**Details.** [Reviewing the bounty documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)...

- A user can only highlight one question at a time and must wait for their selection to expire.
- The user must have a badge in the tag. The badge color is shown in the question list and available as a sorting criterion in the dropdown menu.
- The cost scales up based on how popular the tag is, say from 20 for [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) to 200 for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). If applied to the same question again, the cost increases by max(50 rep, +100%).

  *Other ideas:* (1) higher if the user is part of the Q&A; (2) lower with the age of the Q&A, to a 50% discount for the oldest Q or longest inactive Q&A; (3) lower with the user's badge level, 25% for silver and 50% for gold.

**Comments.**

*Why bother?* Bounties are expensive and carry the mental overhead of deciding who you're going to give rep to and why. Plenty of users have rep to burn and questions they want to highlight for whatever reason. They should not be limited to highlighting only for the purpose of playing king/queen and doling out rewards.

*Incentives.* Like @Dukeling, I think there's no need to tweak the reward side of the gamification program and doing so could have annoying side-effects. Besides, the OP and any answerers will be rewarded by the influx of passersby. If the highlighter needs incentives, offer badges like "highlighted a years-old Q&A and drew +10 votes during its week in the sun."

*Implementation.* Apart from rejiggering the sorting and display in the question list and the requirement that a particular tag be chosen, such a system might piggyback on how bounties are managed..?

Answer (score 1):

**Why I like the proposal of auto-generating bounties on promising unanswered questions:** I think the bounty system has a nice property of adding attention to a question for some time but not forever -- the question gets a lot of eyeballs while it has the bounty but those eyeballs can move elsewhere once the bounty expires. This is much nicer than our current solution for finding interesting unanswered questions, the "Unanswered Questions" list, where a difficult, highly voted question can claim a high spot on the list for years.

**Why I dislike the proposal:** We have the potential to be adding bounties (aka significant reputation bonuses) on questions that may have already been answered in the comments. For instance, I reviewed the top 20 questions in the "Unanswered Questions" list in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (these would be prime candidates for these auto-generated bounties) and found that three questions were solved in the comments, three ended with comments saying "this can't be done because of xyz reasons", and two were filed as bug reports. I don't think it would be a very nice outcome to have 40% of our auto-generated bounties on questions where a comment would be converted immediately to an answer by a rep-hunter, potentially generating significant reputation for little effort.

**Counter-proposal:** I think we should mimic the auto-generated bounty proposal in all ways except for the bounties themselves. We could create a "Questions Needing Attention" list containing the auto-selected questions that are old and highly voted and have questions expire from this list after a certain amount of time, making room for new questions. Instead of rewarding users with reputation bonuses from bounties, we could create a bronze, silver, and gold badge for the number of upvoted answers to questions on the "Questions Needing Attention" list. This proposal seems more light-weight than manually curated "interesting questions lists" and could still draw attention to interesting older questions.

Comment: Is the idea that comment-answer questions would not be there because we're conditioning on being "highly voted"? That sounds like a good improvement to the "needs answer" list. The age thing seems sort of weird, like we'd always be looking one month in the past -- these q's are old enough to qualify, but not so old as to have expired their time on the list. (I'm not the downvoter, btw.)

Answer (score -3):

Stack Exchange should make an institutional change. Remove the "Hottest Questions" or "Newest Questions" boxes on the right side bar and add, "Insert Adjective Bounties". Knowing the bounty would appear in a spot that is known to draw attention would give question writers an incentive to offer bounties. And, as the OP stated, most people are using the Newest queue anyway.

Disclaimer: I found this thread on the "Hottest Questions" sidebar but I would have noticed it eventually anyway.